# Why we could first fix the constructor property and then reset the prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

It's normal that we reset the prototype to achieve inherit.And then we fix the constructor property.But Why we could first fix the constructor property and then reset the prototype?

way1:

```
function inheritPrototype(subType,superType){
    var o1 = Object.create(superType.prototype);
    o1.constructor = subType;
    subType.prototype = o1;
}
```

way2:

```
function inheritPrototype(subType,superType){
    var o1 = Object.create(superType.prototype); 
    subType.prototype = o1;
    o1.constructor = subType;
}
```

When I `console.log(o1.constructor)`, I found both way1 and way2 could change o1.cobstructor. I can understand way2 as it fix the constructor after resetting the prototype (normal). But how about way2? I can't understand way2 still works as the order of`o1.constructor = subType` and `subType.prototype = o1;`is wrong.

PS:
Resetting prototype is like:
`subType. prototype= superType`
Since it changes what subType. prototype points to,we need to fix the constructor

Fixing the constructor is like:
`subType. prototype.constructor= subType`
This makes `subType. prototype.constructor` points to subType again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reset the prototype". Can you please explain what you think happens there, and how that could affect the `constructor` assignment?

Comment: see the PS on the post's bottom

Comment: It still seems you are confused what "setting the prototype" implies. It's just two objects with two normal properties, `.prototype` and `.constructor`. We want them to point to each other. Order doesn't matter, they do not affect each other. What affects the `o1.constructor` is that it inherits the property from `superType.prototype` because of `Object.create`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final paragraph you said that the statement "fixing the constructor" was `subType.prototype.constructor = subType;`, but that's not what it is in your code samples. In your code samples it is `o1.constructor = subType`. If it was the former then the order would matter and only way2 would work.

Instead it uses `o1.constructor = subType`. The order doesn't matter, because `o1` isn't modified by the statement `subType.prototype = o1;` so it can't have any effect on what `o1.constructor = subType` does.

These three versions all work:

```js
function inheritPrototype(subType,superType){
    var o1 = Object.create(superType.prototype);
    subType.prototype = o1;
    o1.constructor = subType;
}
```

```js
function inheritPrototype(subType,superType){
    var o1 = Object.create(superType.prototype);
    o1.constructor = subType;
    subType.prototype = o1;
}
```

```js
function inheritPrototype(subType,superType){
    var o1 = Object.create(superType.prototype);
    subType.prototype = o1;
    subType.prototype.constructor = subType;
}
```

But this one does not, since it sets the constructor property on the old value of `subType.prototype`, instead of on `o1`:

```js
function inheritPrototype(subType,superType){
    var o1 = Object.create(superType.prototype);
    subType.prototype.constructor = subType;
    subType.prototype = o1;
}
```

Comment: Can understand version1, version3 and version4,but still feel version2 is strange. For example,it just like we should first make mistakes and then to correct them instead of first correcting the mistakes and then to make mistakes.

Comment: @Chor You're overthinking it. Instead of thinking of it as a mistake that needs to be fixed, just think about what is happening in a simplified case. Version1 is `const obj = {}; const x = obj; obj.foo = 'bar'; console.log( x.foo );` while Version 2 is `const obj = {}; obj.foo = 'bar'; const x = obj; console.log( x.foo );`

Comment: So here the `subType.prototype = o1;` is like `const x = obj` and the `o1.constructor=subType` is like `obj.foo='bar' `?I figure it out.Thanks for your help.